# Show that $c_0$ is not a Banach space in the $\| \cdot \|_2$-norm.

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, complete-spaces

Denote $c_0 = \{ \xi=(\xi)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} : \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\xi_n = 0 \}$ .

Question: Show that $c_0$ is not a Banach space in the $\| \cdot \|_2$-norm.

I wish to construct a Cauchy sequence $(\xi^{(i)})_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ in $c_0$ such that it does not converge to am element in $c_0.$

First of all, I have trouble seeing $\xi^{(i)}.$ Should I have two indices for each $\xi^{(i)}?$ Because $\xi^{(i)} \in c_0$, meaning that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\xi^{(i)}_n = 0$ for each $i.$

I would be appreciated if someone can provide me a hint to solve the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an even more fundamental reason why $c_0$ cannot be a Banach space with the $|| . ||_{2}$ norm, which is that some elements of $c_0$ do not have a finite $|| . ||_2$ norm!

For example,
$$ \xi = (1, \tfrac 1 {\sqrt 2}, \tfrac 1 {\sqrt 3}, \tfrac 1 {\sqrt 4}, \dots ) \in c_0, $$
but
$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left( \tfrac 1 {\sqrt{n}} \right)^2= \infty.$$

Comment: So I just have to construct a Cauchy sequence in $c_0$ that converges to your $\xi$?

Comment: I'm claiming that we can't even make $c_0$ a _normed space_ with respect to $|| . ||_2$ (let alone a Banach space). So the whole thing is doomed to begin with - there is no need to construct Cauchy sequences.

Comment: I understand your argument now. So can we say that $c_0$ is not a normed space with respect to $\| \cdot \|_p$ where $1 \leq p <\infty$?

Comment: Yes - change the square roots to $p$th roots.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we can't put l-2 norm in C0. As for any 1≤p< inf
lp is a proper subspace of C0. Although C0 is a closed subspace of l-inf. So the question seems to be improper.